# Can't install php8.0-curl on Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: php, ubuntu, apt, php-curl

I'm trying to install php8.0-curl on my server.
But it keeps giving me the following error:

```
$ sudo apt install php8.0-curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php8.0-curl
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php8.0-curl'
```

I followed the following steps, but with no success.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update
sudo apt install curl
sudo apt install php8.0-curl
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to add that PPA, the package exists in the main repo: https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/php8.0-curl

Comment: P.S. Your title says Ubuntu 21.10 but you've tagged 22.04. Which version are you actually asking about?

Comment: @ADyson But then it should still work I suppose?
I removed the tag, thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: `But then it should still work`...yes, unless something has gone very screwy with your apt repo config

Comment: Can you install other php8.0-xxx packages?

Comment: @ADyson I had an issue with apt, so I followed this guide to "reset" apt https://askubuntu.com/a/1305148. Can it cause the problem?

Comment: Not if you did it properly. I assume you altered the commands appropriately to configure the package repos for 21.10 (impish) rather than focal? You should check what package repos are currently configured on your machine in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: @ADyson I think you found the issue. Can I simply replace "focal" with "impish"?

Comment: I believe so, yes

Answer (score 1):

I was using the wrong repositories.
Following this answer solved the issue.
https://serverfault.com/a/1106701